# merge one text with another text and print to new one with change in one field

Tags: linux, awk, sed

> How to handle this through Linux:

**File 1:**

```
1 -b 2 --guide=5 --drop=3 --errors-parse --win-flags="dirwin pc_hard_no,pc_hard_expiry_month,pc_hard_expiry_year,pc_ver with hardvr.type_portals_methods_file WHERE pc_hard_no > 99999999999999 VER pc_hard_expiry_date > '2017-10-31' VER pc_ver > 0 SIZET 0, 1" --ver --timeads=10
```

> File 2:

```
99
1000000
99282828
111
```

> Result:

```
1 -b 2 --guide=5 --drop=3 --errors-parse --win-flags="dirwin pc_hard_no,pc_hard_expiry_month,pc_hard_expiry_year,pc_ver with hardvr.type_portals_methods_file WHERE pc_hard_no > 99999999999999 VER pc_hard_expiry_date > '2017-10-31' VER pc_ver > 0 SIZET 99, 1" --ver --timeads=10
1 -b 2 --guide=5 --drop=3 --errors-parse --win-flags="dirwin pc_hard_no,pc_hard_expiry_month,pc_hard_expiry_year,pc_ver with hardvr.type_portals_methods_file WHERE pc_hard_no > 99999999999999 VER pc_hard_expiry_date > '2017-10-31' VER pc_ver > 0 SIZET 1000000, 1" --ver --timeads=10
1 -b 2 --guide=5 --drop=3 --errors-parse --win-flags="dirwin pc_hard_no,pc_hard_expiry_month,pc_hard_expiry_year,pc_ver with hardvr.type_portals_methods_file WHERE pc_hard_no > 99999999999999 VER pc_hard_expiry_date > '2017-10-31' VER pc_ver > 0 SIZET 99282828, 1" --ver --timeads=10
1 -b 2 --guide=5 --drop=3 --errors-parse --win-flags="dirwin pc_hard_no,pc_hard_expiry_month,pc_hard_expiry_year,pc_ver with hardvr.type_portals_methods_file WHERE pc_hard_no > 99999999999999 VER pc_hard_expiry_date > '2017-10-31' VER pc_ver > 0 SIZET 111, 1" --ver --timeads=10
```

which means i have one file with command in file1 and i need to copy the numbers from file 2 and paste the command to new file line by line with replacing the number after `SIZET`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest take a look if you available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `xargs` + `sed`?

```
$ xargs -I{} -a File2 sed 's/SIZET 0, 1/SIZET {}, 1/' File1
1 -b 2 --guide=5 --drop=3 --errors-parse --win-flags="dirwin pc_hard_no,pc_hard_expiry_month,pc_hard_expiry_year,pc_ver with hardvr.type_portals_methods_file WHERE pc_hard_no > 99999999999999 VER pc_hard_expiry_date > '2017-10-31' VER pc_ver > 0 SIZET 99, 1" --ver --timeads=10
1 -b 2 --guide=5 --drop=3 --errors-parse --win-flags="dirwin pc_hard_no,pc_hard_expiry_month,pc_hard_expiry_year,pc_ver with hardvr.type_portals_methods_file WHERE pc_hard_no > 99999999999999 VER pc_hard_expiry_date > '2017-10-31' VER pc_ver > 0 SIZET 1000000, 1" --ver --timeads=10
1 -b 2 --guide=5 --drop=3 --errors-parse --win-flags="dirwin pc_hard_no,pc_hard_expiry_month,pc_hard_expiry_year,pc_ver with hardvr.type_portals_methods_file WHERE pc_hard_no > 99999999999999 VER pc_hard_expiry_date > '2017-10-31' VER pc_ver > 0 SIZET 99282828, 1" --ver --timeads=10
1 -b 2 --guide=5 --drop=3 --errors-parse --win-flags="dirwin pc_hard_no,pc_hard_expiry_month,pc_hard_expiry_year,pc_ver with hardvr.type_portals_methods_file WHERE pc_hard_no > 99999999999999 VER pc_hard_expiry_date > '2017-10-31' VER pc_ver > 0 SIZET 111, 1" --ver --timeads=10
```